# Make chapter titles in table of contents clickable when using classicthesis

Tags: hyperref, classicthesis

I'm using the `classicthesis` package and I can't figure out how to make the chapter and section titles clickable links in the table of contents. The default behaviour is such that only the page number is clickable.

I tried adding the option `linktoc=all` to the `hyperref`, but that had no effects.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\PassOptionsToPackage{linktoc=all}{hyperref} % this should make the chapters and sections clickable in the toc
% -------------------
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{a}
\section{v}
\section{v}
\chapter{b}
\section{v}
\section{v}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your used style file `classicfile.sty` (I have the version from 2018) the definition in the class for `hyperref` is:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
    \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\thepart=\relax} % no part numbers (i, ii, iii) in PDF outline   IVO
   %\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}} %%%IVO bring back Part numbers in PDF outline
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linktocpage=true,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=CTurl,linkcolor=CTlink,citecolor=CTcitation}
```

As you can see in this code snippet a command `\PassOptionsToPackage` should be used **before** package `hyperref` is called. In your case it yould be called before `\usepackage{classicthesis}`, because in this package is package `hyperref` called the first time.

But you can simply use `\hypersetup{linktoc=all}` in your document code. Please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{classicthesis}


\begin{document}
\hypersetup{linktoc=all} % <============================================
\tableofcontents
\chapter{a}
\section{v}
\section{v}
\chapter{b}
\section{v}
\section{v}
\end{document}
```

and its resulting TOC page:

[image: resulting TOC]

You can see all headings in the TOC are blue as the page numbers, they all are now links to the chapter/section/...